# EXCEL counting empty rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1 Y     Y     Y        X
2                X  X  
3    Y     Y  
4                   X  X
5 Y     Y  Y        X

Count the number of empty rows (from Columns A to E) and put result here. Answer should be 2 from example above.
```

Hi Folks,
I'm struggling to find the correct Excel formula to count the number of rows with no data from columns A through E, and putting that answer in a cell. These 'empty rows' may have data in later columns (like F, G, H), but I just want to count the rows with no data from columns A to E. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this array formula,

```
=SUM(IF(ROW(1:5), IF(A1:A5&B1:B5&C1:C5&D1:D5&E1:E5="", 1)))
```

Remember to finalize with ctrl+shift+enter, not just enter.

Comment: This does seem to work. Thanks much. For future reference of others, would you be willing to give a little explanation of how your solution works?

Comment: The Formulas, Formula Auditing, Evaluate Formula is already designed to do that.

Comment: Yes, I did confirm it as an array formula and it works great. Thanks also for the reference to 'Evaluate Formula'. I wasn't aware of that ability.

Answer (score 2):

Since array formulas tend to confuse people, here's a non-Array formula approach:

Place `=IF(COUNTA(A1:E1)=0,1,0)` into row 1 of (for example) column I and drag down to row 5.  Then place a sum formula below that to get the answer, for example: `=SUM(I1:I5)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, my spreadsheet has over 900 columns, and I don't have room for an extra column to do what you suggest. This pattern of looking for blank sections is repeated over 100 times throughout my spreadsheet. Therefore, I appreciate the solution that doesn't require a separate 'tally' column. However, your solution does work as you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a variation on the standard formula for getting row sums of a 2d array

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(N(A1:E5=""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:E5)^0))=COLUMNS(A1:E5)))
```

or

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(N(A1:E5="Y"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:E5)^0))=0))
```

Again they are array formulas and have to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>